# How to response with JSON format using Ruby Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rack, middleware

How to reply a simple ruby rack server with JSON object , lets assume mt server is something like :

```
app = Proc.new do |env| 
  [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }, ['Some body']]
end 

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => 4001, :threaded => true)
```

and lets assume instead of some body text I want a JSON object with something like :

```
{
"root": [
    {
        "function": null
    }
]
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Include the "json" gem in your project, and then call `#to_json` on the Hash:

```
app = Proc.new do |env| 
  [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, [ { :x => 42 }.to_json ]]
end
```

Note that `nil` is translated to `null` in the JSON, if you need `null`.